# Get 2 selected value and pass to button for display

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

What's the best way for me to get both selected value from the 2 selection list and display the image from an array once the user hit the button? Is it possible?

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming1" (ionChange)='valuechange(gaming1)'>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let item of allList" [value]="item.values">{{item.name}}</ion-option> 
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
     <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming2">
       <ng-container *ngFor="let item of allList">
         <ion-option [value]="item.values" *ngIf="item.flag==0">{{item.name}}</ion-option> 
       </ng-container>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<button ion-button block (click)="getData(gaming1 + gaming2)">Pass Data</button>
```

Component .ts file, i tested the function for button its working but I dont know how to show the image back to html file:

```
public allList: any;
      public endPlaces: any;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){

        this.allList=[{
          name:'NES',
          values:'nes',
          flag:0
        },{
          name:'Nintendo64',
          values:'n64',
          flag:0
        },{
          name:'PlayStation',
          values:'ps',
          flag:0
        }];

        this.endPlaces=[{
          name:'Dota',
          values:'nesn64',
          image:'assests/img/dotajpg'
        },{
          name:'CSGO',
          values:'nesps',
          image:'assets/img/csgo.jpg'
        },{
          name:'Overwatch',
          values:'nes',
          image:'assets/img/overwatch.jpg'
        }]

      }

      valuechange(key){

          for(let i = 0 ; i < this.allList.length ; i++){
            if( this.allList[i].values==key){
              this.allList[i].flag=1;
            }else{
              this.allList[i].flag=0;
            }
          }

      }

      getData(selectedValue){

        for(let i = 0 ; i < this.endPlaces.length ; i++){
        if( this.endPlaces[i].values==selectedValue){
          console.log("Selected", this.endPlaces[i].name);
        }else{
          console.log("dangggg");
        }
      }
      }
    }
```

Update:[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVwns.png)

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Suggestion: Use angular services (Injectables) to provide hard coded data. Much cleaner and SOC! Btw, are you adding strings and passing them to getData() ? Could you log your  selectedData parameter and let v us know what you see?

Comment: Im not familiar with angular services, I have updated the console log for it. Tq. @AnjilDhamala

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parameters comma separated to controller like:

```
    <!--In HTML file-->
        <img src="{{matchEndPlace.image}}">
        <button ion-button block (click)="getData(gaming1, gaming2)">Pass Data</button>


//in TS file
matchEndPlace: any = {};
getData(gaming1, gaming2){
   let matchString = gaming1.toLowerCase() + gaming2.toLowerCase();
   this.matchEndPlace = this.endPlaces.find(e => e.values === matchString) || {};
}

this.endPlaces=[{
          name:'Dota',
          values:'nesn64',
          image:'./assests/img/dotajpg'
        },{
          name:'CSGO',
          values:'nesps',
          image:'./assets/img/csgo.jpg'
        },{
          name:'Overwatch',
          values:'nes',
          image:'./assets/img/overwatch.jpg'
        }]
```

Comment: It's working and I checked it by adding `console.log("working", matchString);` but the images still not showing. @Aman

Comment: There was a typo is <img src="{{matchEndPlace.image}}", did you try after fixing?

Comment: did you try changing img link to "image:'./assets/img/overwatch.jpg'"? I edited my answer.